# invalid proof positivity of fourier transforms

Tags: integration, trigonometry, proof-verification, fourier-transform

I just skimmed through this paper [on positivity of fourier transforms](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/D232B9DEB4819E4D2FF17E8162B8B066/S0004972700047511a.pdf/on_positivity_of_fourier_transforms.pdf) where it is shown that the sine transform
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(x t) \mathrm{d}x$$
is positive if $f$ is decreasing. The proof seems to be pretty straightforward, but at some point, (I assume) the following step is made:
$$\begin{align}
  \int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(x t) \mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \\
  & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left[ \int_0^{\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta + \int_\pi^{2\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \right] \\
  & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left[ \int_0^{\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta + \int_0^{\pi} -f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j + \pi}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \right] \\
  & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \int_0^{\pi} \left[ f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) - f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t} + \frac{\pi}{t}\right) \right] \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}$$
from which the conclusion is drawn that if $f$ is decreasing for $x \geq 0$, the sine transform will be **positive**.

However, by performing this step slightly differently, I found
$$\begin{align}
  \int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(x t) \mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \\
  & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left[ \int_0^{\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta + \int_\pi^{2\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \right] \\
  & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left[ \int_\pi^{2\pi} -f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j - \pi}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta + \int_\pi^{2\pi} f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \right] \\
  & = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \int_\pi^{2\pi} \left[ f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) - f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t} - \frac{\pi}{t}\right) \right] \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}$$
from which it would follow that if $f$ is decreasing for $x \geq 0$, the sine transform would be **negative**.

My question is thus: where did I make the mistake to get this contradicting result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still positive. Note that if $f$ is decreasing then

$$f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right)\le f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t} - \frac{\pi}{t}\right)\implies f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t}\right) - f\left(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi j}{t} - \frac{\pi}{t}\right)\le 0$$

And $\sin(x)\le 0$ for $x\in[\pi,2\pi]$. Hence the integrand is positive.

Comment: I forgot about the sign of the $\sin$ function, Thanks a lot!